# Downloading a file from DataBase by decoding the encoded String format of a file

Tags: java, spring

> I encoded a file name in String format and stored in a table column
>   file. Now in another method i want to download that file to a
>   particular local path. so i'm decoding the file saving it in that
>   path,file is getting created but content in the file is missing,that
>   means empty file is getting created.

```
could you please help me to overcome this issue

try{
        session=getSession();
        ProjectsDO project = em.find(ProjectsDO.class, id);
          //got the encode file from db
        String encodedFile=project.getProjectFile();

//  decoding the file to actual file
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedFile);
        String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);

//saving the file to required path
         FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/veerraju/Desktop/sap/projects/"+decodedString
); 
           System.out.println("file created succefully");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


//this is the method used to encode only file name(that means it encodes"quote.jpg".
String originalInput = "C:/Users/veerraju/Desktop/sap/quote.jpg"; //cXVvdGUuanBn
    File file=new File(originalInput);
    String fileName=file.getName();
        String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileName.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to store a file is as byte[], Clob,Blob. You have created an FileOutputStream to write the file content, but you did not populated it with data. So you might have failed on one of two scenarios:

- you are keeping only the file name in the database, if so, then the file would be empty from the start
- you have used the content as in your path, creating an invalid path to your output file, log the path first, is it a corrent one.

So let's assume you have this model:

```
class ProjectsDO {

    private String fileName;
    private byte[] fileContent;
    // getters and setters
}
```

And your method would look like this:

```
    try{
        session = getSession();
        ProjectsDO project = em.find(ProjectsDO.class, id);
        // read the file name or the full path
        String fileName=project.getFileName();

        // read the content of the file
        byte[] fileContent = project.getFileContent();

       //compute the output file path (combine directory and file name)
       Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/veerraju/Desktop/sap/projects/"+fileName);
       // this path was missing - fill the file with content
       Files.write(path,fileContent);
         System.out.println("file created succefully");
       } catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
```

Of course you can encode the file content, but for simplicity of this task, I have skipped this part.

UPDATE:

In order to convert file to bytes[]:

```
   byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

If your DB does not support byte[] column type, then you will need to persist it as a varchar/text column, but it will be worse in performance.

Comment: hi beri, thank you so much for your response.so I need to store the encoded String of a file to the fileContent column in a DB?

Comment: I do not know if encoding is your requirement, but in order to persist in the DB it's not necessary. Simply convert file content to a byte[] and persist in your column. Most databases and ORM will support it

Comment: I have done as you suggested, it worked well. but the column in a table which stores fileContent of byte[] type is capable of storing the length of 255, where the actual length of the fileContent exceeding length 255.i tried compressing and decompressing the bytr[], but same issue. could you suggest some better idea

Comment: Depends on your database, you need to read their documentation, You need a type designed to store any size, like text, or oid in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You can resolve it in a cheaper way. Store only path to a file. And all file will be stored on a mounted drive. Or a local directory when working On local machine